# AngularJS-Smart-Table Deleting row does not delete row's selection in options menu

Tags: html, angularjs, web, web-applications, smart-table

Stack,

I have a smart table generating rows when the user clicks add and deleting them when they click the relevant row remove button. This, for the most part, works, except there is a "common type" selection box to autofill most of the data in a row which is only being deleted if it is in the final row of the table and then removed.

I have made an image attempting to explain how this works from the output:

[image: Attempting to explain how this effects output]

**Upon removal of the second row of data in the data above**

[image]

I'm unsure of the problem solving approach to fix this, as the removal of wunits and their data from the row is working fine. Would someone be able to explain how one might go about fixing the issue with select or point me in the right direction for material (I'm still a complete novice to web development in general).

Below are the relevant snippets of code from the function called on the removal button being pressed and the html for the body of the table, where the model is being manipulated to generate new rows.

```js
        $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(removeID)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.wunits.length; i++)
            {
                if($scope.wunits[i].id === removeID.id)
                {
                    $scope.wunits.splice(i, 1);
                    $scope.selectedCommonType.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
```

```html
        <table class="w3-container w3-red" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="wunits" class="table table-striped">

            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="wunit in wunits | filter:selected.iwtfReference  track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input ng-model = "wunit.reference" placeholder="{{wunit.reference}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="selectedCommonType"
                            ng-options="common.name for common in commonWastes" >
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-if="!selectedCommonType" ng-model="wunit.name">
                    <input ng-model="wunit.name" ng-if="selectedCommonType" placeholder="{{selectedCommonType.name}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-if="!selectedCommonType" ng-model="wunit.description">
                    <input ng-model="wunit.description" ng-if="selectedCommonType" placeholder="{{selectedCommonType.desc}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="wunit.quantity">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-if="!selectedCommonType" ng-model="wunit.weight">
                    <input ng-model="wunit.weight" ng-if="selectedCommonType" placeholder="{{selectedCommonType.weight}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-if="!selectedCommonType" ng-model="wunit.volume">
                    <input ng-model="wunit.volume" ng-if="selectedCommonType" placeholder="{{selectedCommonType.volume}}">
                </td>
                <td class="w3-size w3-tiny">
                    <input ng-if="!selectedCommonType" ng-model="wunit.codes">
                    <input ng-model="wunit.codes" ng-if="selectedCommonType" placeholder="{{selectedCommonType.codes}}">
                </td>
                <td>{{wunit.producer}}</td>
                <td>{{wunit.producerReference}}</td>
                <td>{{wunit.producerSite}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="removeItem(wunit)">Remove Record</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

If there is any other relevant information you might need, please let me know.

Connor

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass the index to the function and delete the item from array

```
<td>
   <button ng-click="removeItem(wunit,$index)">Remove Record</button>
</td>
```

can you try rewriting your java script as this ?

```
$scope.removeItem = function removeItem(removeID,index)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.wunits.length; i++)
        {
            if($scope.wunits[i].id === removeID.id)
            {
                $scope.wunits.splice(i, 1);
                $scope.selectedCommonType.splice(index, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

your deleting from same index from your main object also.
$scope.selectedCommonType index is not i. i is the correct index for wunits

Comment: Sorry Aslam but these changes seem to break the table more than removing the wunit based on ID, and havent changed the issue with the select box. Maybe other parts of the code I've not added to the snippet are affecting it (or more likely my inexperience means my code is acting unpredictably...heh).

Comment: you want to delete the selected items when you press delete button?

Comment: I would like to reset the selection box when I delete that row, as at the moment when that row is removed the selection box keeps its selection and "stays still" in the table when the rows move up to fill blank spots. I will try and take another screencap to illustrate this.

Comment: Excuse my mistake but in recreating the data to add the second picture I used paint tins (s) instead of (l). If I had used (l) the explained effect would still have happened.

Comment: Corrected it for sake of understanding.

Comment: your deleting from same index from your main object also. $scope.selectedCommonType index is not i. i is the correct index for wunits.
please refer the updated answer.

Comment: Ah. Your suggestion does make total sense, but unfortunately it is not working as intended. Your suggested code change seems to have no impact at all :/

Comment: please update the object structure.
I can try to give you the solution.

simple question . why do you need to splice this $scope.selectedCommonType.splice(i, 1);?
your requirement is to delete the row from the wunits rit ?

please try to splice  $scope.wunits.splice(index, 1); in the above code..
it should work

Comment: Splicing commontype was an attempt to remove the selection. It is not necessary. 

The reason I splice wunits based on ID is partially how my table is generated. In the smart table documentation their example generates rows based on the elements in an array (the only difference is that I filter my table to display only rows that have the same reference once selected) not based upon the index of the row. Refactoring to delete based on index makes the smart table exhibit weird behaviour. 

The requirement at the moment isn't to delete the row (this works) it is to reset the autofill box.